# Body is empty during POST method to server controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, backend

I'm requesting a send response from my client containing an object, but on my back-end, when i console.log(req.body), the server shows it being a blank object..

It's pretty much a copy paste from an example I did in the past, sending and requesting an object to post to a db..

Heres what I have:

this is in 'api.js'

```
var postBaseNums = data => {
    console.log(data)
    fetch('/getnums', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(res => res.send())
}
```

'data' is the object I'm wanting to send, and here i console.log(data) to ensure that its not empty or anything, which its not.

This gets sent to my /getnums route which sends it to the post method on my backend:

```
postNums: (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    numSchem.create({
        num: req.body
    })
    .then(data => res.status(201).json(data))
    .catch(e => {
        req.error = e
        console.log(e)
        next()
    })
}
```

Here, console.log(req.body) shows in terminal '{}'

I've tried changing body to just body: data rather than stringifying it, same thing.

After reviewing my mongoose schema, I now get this error:

```
numSchema validation failed: field1: Cast to String failed 
for value "{}" at path "field1"
```

which makes sense because body is an empty object..though i feel that it should be a string because in api.js i have: body: JSON.stringify(data)

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you do `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d 'YOUR_DATA' http://<YOUR_HOST>/getnums` from your terminal and check if the data is logged. If it is then the issue is in your client else issue is in server

Comment: it logged {}

So issue is on the server. kk. ill go check my server stuff.

Thats a nifty little command. Thanks. You learn something new everyday.

Comment: curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{'field1':'hi'}' http://localhost:3000/getnums

outputs:

{"_id":"5b880a8054efb26227569750","__v":0}

So now im able to put but with no data..

Comment: sorry try this `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d 'YOUR_DATA' http://<YOUR_HOST>/getnums` Notice the POST method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `express` as your server or something similar

Install Body Parser

`npm install --save body-parser`

Add middleware

```
//Add this where you initialize the server app
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() )


//Your req.body is now parsed
postNums: (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    //...stuff
}
```

Comment: I already had body parser, but had: // app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
which i changed to app.use(bodyParser.json()) and that fixed it. Thank you very much.